# im trying to allow a button in tkinter to be pressed using the keyboard key

Tags: user-interface, button, tkinter

this part of code shows the buttons as they are know to be used in tkinter

```
up = Radiobutton(frame1, text="up", variable=rows, value=1,indicatoron=0)#button for movingup
up.grid( row=2,column=0 )

down = Radiobutton(frame1, text="down", variable=rows, value=2,indicatoron=0)#button for moving down
down.grid( row=3,column=0 )


left = Radiobutton(frame1, text="left", variable=cols, value=3,indicatoron=0)#button for moving left
left.grid( row=2,column=4 )
right = Radiobutton(frame1, text="right", variable=cols, value=4,indicatoron=0)#button for moving #right
right.grid( row=3,column=4 )

vertical=Entry(frame1,bd=2,width=10)
vertical.grid(row=4,column=0)


horizontal=Entry(frame1,bd=2,width=10)
horizontal.grid(row=4,column=4)

enter=Button(main,text='Enter',command=move) #displays the move on grid once button is pressed
enter.pack()


label = Label(main)
label.pack()
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to ask good questions and also, please put a minimal, complete and verifiable example in the question (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that it's easier to see what is the problem

Comment: Please don't link to code on another site.

Comment: Do you want the button to be pressed when the keyboard key is pressed or do you just want to call the button command with a keyboard shortcut? If it is the latter, see http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/events.html about event and binding.

Comment: keyboard shortcut

Answer (score 0):

You can bind function to key - ie.

```
root.bind('m', move) # key `m`
root.bind('<Control-m>', move) # key `Ctrl+m`
root.bind('<Alt-m>', move) # key `Alt+m`
root.bind('M', move) # key `Shift+m`
```

but it will be executed with extra argument

```
move(event)
```

so you have to define function with extra argument too

```
def move(event=None)
```

and you can set default value for `event` (ie. `None`) so it will work also with `command=move`